# Assign a sequential number to a new variable with irregular patterns

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to assign a sequential number (a new variable HospID) to a instance of hospitalizations by patient ID. For example, if a patient was admitted into a hospital A and be transferred to hospital B and then to hospital C, each hospital had a hospitalization record. However, all three records belonged to the same instance of hospitalization (same HospID).

The transfers are identified as the admit datetime of the second record happened within or after 24 hours of the previous record, that is, admitDateTime - PreviousDisDateTime = (-24h, 24h).

As the transfers are identified by comparing the record with previous one, if there are transfers, the very first record of the specific hospitalization is transfer=NO, followed by transfer==Yes.

There may be more than 1 transfers, that is, consecutive transfer= Yes. These transfers will have the same HospID as the very first record of the specific hospitalization (Transfers=No).

For example,
Patient 1, for obsID= 2-8, Transfers=="NO", followed by 6 transfers=="Yes", the 7 records are considered as the same Hospitalizaiton (HospID=2);
Patient 2, for obsID= 2 and obsID=3, Transfers=="NO", followed by a record with Transfers=="Yes", these two records belong to the same instance of hospitalization (HospID=2);
Patient 2, for obsID= 4 -8, Transfers=="NO" & lead(Transfers, n=4)=="Yes"~~~~~~~~HospID=3;
Patient 2, for obsID= 9and obsID=10, Transfers=="NO" & lead(Transfers, n=1)=="Yes"~~~~~~~~HospID=4

The data sample and expected HospID is as below:

| ID | PatientID | obsID | Diff_admi_dis | Transfers | HospID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Patient1 | 1 | NA | NO | 1 |
| 2 | Patient1 | 2 | 8974.52 | NO | 2 |
| 3 | Patient1 | 3 | 2.35 | Yes | 2 |
| 4 | Patient1 | 4 | 1.77 | Yes | 2 |
| 5 | Patient1 | 5 | 8.22 | Yes | 2 |
| 6 | Patient1 | 6 | 3.53 | Yes | 2 |
| 7 | Patient1 | 7 | 7.02 | Yes | 2 |
| 8 | Patient1 | 8 | 0.63 | Yes | 2 |
| 9 | Patient2 | 1 | NA | NO | 1 |
| 10 | Patient2 | 2 | 21603.08 | NO | 2 |
| 11 | Patient2 | 3 | 22.58 | Yes | 2 |
| 12 | Patient2 | 4 | 442.58 | NO | 3 |
| 13 | Patient2 | 5 | 6.67 | Yes | 3 |
| 14 | Patient2 | 6 | 1.60 | Yes | 3 |
| 15 | Patient2 | 7 | 2.75 | Yes | 3 |
| 16 | Patient2 | 8 | 1.42 | Yes | 3 |
| 17 | Patient2 | 9 | 2321.33 | NO | 4 |
| 18 | Patient2 | 10 | 1.45 | Yes | 4 |

The variable Diff_admi_dis is the time difference between admitDateTime and the previous dismissDateTime.      I have tried the code as below.

```
    dfhospNew.1<-dfhospNew %>% group_by(PatientID)%>% arrange(obsID) %>%  
    mutate(HospID=case_when(Transfers =="NO"& obsID ==1 ~ 1,
                        lag(Transfers, n=1) == "NO" & Transfers =="NO"& obsID>1 ~ lag(HospID)+1,
                        lag(Transfers, n=1) == "NO" & Transfers =="Yes" & obsID>1 ~ lag(HospID),
                        lag(Transfers, n=1) == "Yes" & Transfers =="NO" & obsID>1 ~ lag(HospID)+1,
                        lag(Transfers, n=1) == "Yes" & Transfers =="Yes" & obsID>1 ~lag(HospID)
          )
      )%>%
    ungroup()
```

How to generate the new variable HospID as a sequential number of hospitalizations while considering transfers? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may want to increase your `HospID` whenever `Transfers` is "NO". If that's true, you could use `cumsum` (cumulative sum) of whenever this occurs, and simplify:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>% 
  arrange(PatientID, obsID) %>%
  mutate(NewHospID = cumsum(Transfers == "NO"))
```

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

**Output**

```
      ID PatientID obsID Diff_admi_dis Transfers HospID NewHospID
   <int> <chr>     <int>         <dbl> <chr>      <int>     <int>
 1     1 Patient1      1         NA    NO             1         1
 2     2 Patient1      2       8975.   NO             2         2
 3     3 Patient1      3          2.35 Yes            2         2
 4     4 Patient1      4          1.77 Yes            2         2
 5     5 Patient1      5          8.22 Yes            2         2
 6     6 Patient1      6          3.53 Yes            2         2
 7     7 Patient1      7          7.02 Yes            2         2
 8     8 Patient1      8          0.63 Yes            2         2
 9     9 Patient2      1         NA    NO             1         1
10    10 Patient2      2      21603.   NO             2         2
11    11 Patient2      3         22.6  Yes            2         2
12    12 Patient2      4        443.   NO             3         3
13    13 Patient2      5          6.67 Yes            3         3
14    14 Patient2      6          1.6  Yes            3         3
15    15 Patient2      7          2.75 Yes            3         3
16    16 Patient2      8          1.42 Yes            3         3
17    17 Patient2      9       2321.   NO             4         4
18    18 Patient2     10          1.45 Yes            4         4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much for your help @Ben